# PHP не обрабатывает два скрипта одновременно

Tags: php, многопоточность, сокет

Есть код, который создаёт UDP socket, принимает и выводит на экран то что пришло по UDP. Через ajax его вызываю, всё работает хорошо, но только в одном браузере, если подключиться с другого компьютера, то не работает или начинает работать на каком нибудь одном компьютере. А мне нужно, чтобы работало, ну как минимум на двух или трёх разных компьютерах.

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP); 
socket_bind($socket, '0.0.0.0', 4001); 
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 50, 0, $from, $port); 
echo $buf;
socket_close($socket);
```

Comment: Ну так один порт только одному сокету за раз отдать можно

Comment: rjhdby, а как это можно реализовать по другому? Хотябы принцип?

Answer (score 0):

Перепробовал много вариантов разных, рассматривал даже nodejs, но как по мне этот пакет уж очень громоздкий. Ничего умного не придумал, как установил приложение Tornado для Python. Создал себе сколько нужно серверов которые слушают порты и переадресовывают их на другие порты, потом с помощью ajax запросов собирал данные с портов. Вроде неплохо и очень просто получилось:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding=utf-8
import tornado.web
import socket
import os
import errno
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.platform.auto import set_close_exec


class UDPServer1(object):
    def __init__(self, io_loop=None):
        self.io_loop = io_loop
        self._sockets = {}  # fd -> socket object
        self._pending_sockets = []
        self._started = False

    def add_sockets(self, sockets):
        if self.io_loop is None:
            self.io_loop = IOLoop.instance()

        for sock in sockets:
            self._sockets[sock.fileno()] = sock
            add_accept_handler(sock, self._on_recive,
                               io_loop=self.io_loop)

    def bind(self, port, address=None, family=socket.AF_UNSPEC, backlog=25):
        sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address, family=family,
                               backlog=backlog)
        if self._started:
            self.add_sockets(sockets)
        else:
            self._pending_sockets.extend(sockets)

    def start(self, num_processes=1):
        assert not self._started
        self._started = True
        if num_processes != 1:
            process.fork_processes(num_processes)
        sockets = self._pending_sockets
        self._pending_sockets = []
        self.add_sockets(sockets)

    def stop(self):
        for fd, sock in self._sockets.iteritems():
            self.io_loop.remove_handler(fd)
            sock.close()

    def _on_recive(self, data, address):
         global w1
         w1 = data
#         print (w1)

def bind_sockets(port, address=None, family=socket.AF_UNSPEC, backlog=25):
    sockets = []
    if address == "":
        address = None
    flags = socket.AI_PASSIVE
    if hasattr(socket, "AI_ADDRCONFIG"):
        flags |= socket.AI_ADDRCONFIG
    for res in set(socket.getaddrinfo(address, port, family, socket.SOCK_DGRAM,
                                  0, flags)):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr = res
        sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
        set_close_exec(sock.fileno())
        if os.name != 'nt':
            sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        if af == socket.AF_INET6:
            if hasattr(socket, "IPPROTO_IPV6"):
                sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_V6ONLY, 1)
        sock.setblocking(0)
        sock.bind(sockaddr)
        sockets.append(sock)
    return sockets

if hasattr(socket, 'AF_UNIX'):
    def bind_unix_socket(file, mode=0600, backlog=128):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        set_close_exec(sock.fileno())
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.setblocking(0)
        try:
            st = os.stat(file)
        except OSError, err:
            if err.errno != errno.ENOENT:
                raise
        else:
            if stat.S_ISSOCK(st.st_mode):
                os.remove(file)
            else:
                raise ValueError("File %s exists and is not a socket", file)
        sock.bind(file)
        os.chmod(file, mode)
        sock.listen(backlog)
        return sock


def add_accept_handler(sock, callback, io_loop=None):
    if io_loop is None:
        io_loop = IOLoop.instance()

    def accept_handler(fd, events):
        while True:
            try:
                data, address = sock.recvfrom(2500)
            except socket.error, e:
                if e.args[0] in (errno.EWOULDBLOCK, errno.EAGAIN):
                    return
                raise
            callback(data, address)
    io_loop.add_handler(sock.fileno(), accept_handler, IOLoop.READ)
###################################################################




#######UDP2#############    
class UDPServer2(object):
    def __init__(self, io_loop=None):
        self.io_loop = io_loop
        self._sockets = {}  # fd -> socket object
        self._pending_sockets = []
        self._started = False

    def add_sockets(self, sockets):
        if self.io_loop is None:
            self.io_loop = IOLoop.instance()

        for sock in sockets:
            self._sockets[sock.fileno()] = sock
            add_accept_handler(sock, self._on_recive,
                               io_loop=self.io_loop)

    def bind(self, port, address=None, family=socket.AF_UNSPEC, backlog=25):
        sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address, family=family,
                               backlog=backlog)
        if self._started:
            self.add_sockets(sockets)
        else:
            self._pending_sockets.extend(sockets)

    def start(self, num_processes=1):
        assert not self._started
        self._started = True
        if num_processes != 1:
            process.fork_processes(num_processes)
        sockets = self._pending_sockets
        self._pending_sockets = []
        self.add_sockets(sockets)

    def stop(self):
        for fd, sock in self._sockets.iteritems():
            self.io_loop.remove_handler(fd)
            sock.close()

    def _on_recive(self, data, address):
         global w2
         w2 = data
#        print (w)

def bind_sockets(port, address=None, family=socket.AF_UNSPEC, backlog=25):
    sockets = []
    if address == "":
        address = None
    flags = socket.AI_PASSIVE
    if hasattr(socket, "AI_ADDRCONFIG"):
        flags |= socket.AI_ADDRCONFIG
    for res in set(socket.getaddrinfo(address, port, family, socket.SOCK_DGRAM,
                                  0, flags)):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr = res
        sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
        set_close_exec(sock.fileno())
        if os.name != 'nt':
            sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        if af == socket.AF_INET6:
            if hasattr(socket, "IPPROTO_IPV6"):
                sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_V6ONLY, 1)
        sock.setblocking(0)
        sock.bind(sockaddr)
        sockets.append(sock)
    return sockets

if hasattr(socket, 'AF_UNIX'):
    def bind_unix_socket(file, mode=0600, backlog=128):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        set_close_exec(sock.fileno())
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.setblocking(0)
        try:
            st = os.stat(file)
        except OSError, err:
            if err.errno != errno.ENOENT:
                raise
        else:
            if stat.S_ISSOCK(st.st_mode):
                os.remove(file)
            else:
                raise ValueError("File %s exists and is not a socket", file)
        sock.bind(file)
        os.chmod(file, mode)
        sock.listen(backlog)
        return sock


def add_accept_handler(sock, callback, io_loop=None):
    if io_loop is None:
        io_loop = IOLoop.instance()

    def accept_handler(fd, events):
        while True:
            try:
                data, address = sock.recvfrom(2500)
            except socket.error, e:
                if e.args[0] in (errno.EWOULDBLOCK, errno.EAGAIN):
                    return
                raise
            callback(data, address)
    io_loop.add_handler(sock.fileno(), accept_handler, IOLoop.READ)
#############################################


#############WEB1###########
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def set_default_headers(self):
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
    def get(self):
        self.write(w1)


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])      
#################################


#############WEB2###########
class MainHandler2(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def set_default_headers(self):
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
    def get(self):
        self.write(w2)

def make_app2():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler2),
    ])      
#################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serv1 = UDPServer1()
    serv1.bind(4001)
    serv1.start()
    serv2 = UDPServer2()
    serv2.bind(4002)
    serv2.start()
    app1 = make_app()
    app1.listen(8801)
    app2 = make_app2()
    app2.listen(8802)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Здесь скрипт слушает два UDP порта 4001 и 4002 и переадресовывает на порты 8801 и 8802 можно просто зайти по адресу localhost:8801 или если с удалённого компьютера, то - IPadress:8801 например и увидеть принятое значение на UDP порту сервера localhost:4001. Также само можно посмотреть и что пришло по UDP порту 4002. К порту 8801 и 8802 можно обращаться с разных машин одновременно, ничего не блокируется и не тормозит... С помощью ajax запросов тоже можно. Сначала возникала проблема кросдоменных запросов, но здесь она решена, добавлением в ответ сервера заголовков. В данном скрипте эта проблема решена. Не знаю, можно так делать или нет, но я просто нашел нужный скрипт и переделал его под себя. Вроде работает. Скрипт нужно поместить в автозагрузку сервера, чтобы после перезагрузки всё автоматически запускалось и работало. Если обратится к серверу до того, как пришел UDP пакет, то сервер возвращает ошибку 500, как это убрать я еще не знаю, но на мою систему это не влияет, ajax запрос ничего при этом не возвращает, до получения данных на UDP порту.